# R and histogram making (with breaks)

Tags: r, histogram

I am a newbie to R- I got this file from Professor. In the Groesse col. u have 1004 col.s altogether

```
 lnr Klasse Gesch Alter Groesse Gewicht Mathe Physik Deutsch Bio Fehltage
   1      6     w    12     124      42     3     NA       2   3        2
   2      5     w    12     146      39     4     NA       2   2        3
   3     10     w    17     174      64     4      3       5   2        4
   4      8     w    15     138      53     5      6       4   3        0
   5      8     w    15     147      56     5      4       3   2        3
   6      9     m    16     162      65     2      2       4   2        2
   7      6     w    14     141      49     2     NA       2   3        2
   8     10     w    16     166      60     5      5       1   3        2
   9      6     w    13     152      44     4     NA       2   2        1
  10      5     w    12     151      39     5     NA       4   4        4
  11      6     w    13     154      46     2     NA       2   1        4
  12      5     w    12     163      41     1     NA       5   1        4
  13      6     m    12     139      47     5     NA       5   4        1
  14      7     w    14     145      51     4     NA       5   5        2
  15      8     w    14     157      49     5      5       4   2        1
  16      7     w    14     159      49     4     NA       2   3        1
  17      9     w    15     149      55     1      2       3   2        3
  18      6     m    13     144      49     1     NA       3   1        6
  19     11     m    17     190      71     5      5       3   2        1
  20      6     m    12     150      46     3     NA       2   3        6
  21      9     w    17     165      65     3      6       5   1        5
  22      5     w    13     151      47     2     NA       5   4        2
  23     10     w    17     154      65     5      3       4   4        5
```

Here is the result:

```
Daten <-  read.csv(file="C:/Users/WillieEkaPutra/Documents/D.Studium/Sem3/Stati 1/Uebung/Schueler.csv")
hist(Daten$Groesse)
# Error in hist.default(Daten$Groesse) : 'x' must be numeric

hist(as.numeric(Daten$Groesse))
# Error in hist.default(as.numeric(Daten$Groesse)) : 
#
#  invalid number of 'breaks'

hist(as.numeric(Daten$Groesse), breaks= 1)
# Error in hist.default(as.numeric(Daten$Groesse), breaks = 1) : 
#   character(0)
# In addition: Warning messages:
# 1: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
# 2: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf

hist(as.numeric(Daten$Groesse), breaks= 1)
# Error in hist.default(as.numeric(Daten$Groesse), breaks = 1004) : 
#  character(0)
# In addition: Warning messages:
# 1: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
# 2: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

Anyone knows, what is wrong? I will be so happy for any help.
regards,
wili

Comment: What is the result of `class(Daten$Groesse) ; summary(Daten$Groesse)`? The sample you've included works fine for me with just `hist`.

Comment: Following up on @hrbrmstr I think by using as.numeric() without thinking about why you have to is probably the first problem. Don't try to just bandaid over the problem, figure out what the first issue is.

Comment: whats the output of class(Daten$Groesse) ?
I tried your code and hist(Daten$Groesse) works just fine for me:
Worst case: Copy your data into a new excel file and save it as txt.
Then execute your code again. using 
    Daten <- read.table("file.txt" header=TRUE)

Comment: @hrbmstr well, it returns this :                                   > class (y)
[1] "NULL"

Comment: @maRtin > Daten <- read.table(file="C:/Users/WillieEkaPutra/Documents/.../Schueler.txt") header=TRUE) 
Error: unexpected symbol in "Daten <- read.table(file="C:/Users/WillieEkaPutra/Documents/D.Studium../Schueler.txt") header"

Comment: try hist(Daten$Groesse[is.finite(Daten$Groesse)])  or, to see the problem, which(!is.finite(Daten$Groesse)).  Could try is.na(...) too.

Comment: If the data (or some portion thereof which still produces the problem) could be shared e.g. via Dropbox and such, I'd say this would be the best way to avoid all the guesswork. Also, the summary , as @hrbrmstr suggested, and also table(Daten$Groesse,useNA="always") might be informative, unless it's too long. I suggest adding the output of those to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@WillieEkaputra you have to delete the bracket after the path and put a comma there. Like this:

```
Daten <- read.table(file="C:/Users/WillieEkaPutra/Documents/.../Schueler.txt", header=TRUE)
```

This should make it work, if the path is right.

Answer (score 1):

will you keep **read.csv(file = "url of your file", header = T and sep = ";")** like this and instead of ;(semicolon) use separator of your record